# Termination of flops vs termination of D-flops

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, flips-flops

It is known that any sequence of $D$-flops eventually terminates (in dimension at most four and with canonical singularities) where $D$ is an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor which is negative against any flopping curve.

Is it known if a sequence of honest flops terminates? (In low dimensions and mild singularities) Here, by "terminates", I mean that it eventually factors through the identity.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you allowing to vary the divisor class $D$ as the terms in the sequence progress?  If so, then I expect that there are counterexamples coming from the infinite groups of birational automorphisms of some Calabi-Yau manifolds (roughly the same issue as in the Kawamata-Morrison Cone Conjecture).

Comment: Dear Jason, I was thinking to take $D=0$, so that the flops is not a $D$-flop, but it is a flop in the classic sense.  Also, I am aware of the example of Kawamata, I was wondering if there are some results in the case of positive Kodaira dimension.

Comment: The product of a Calabi-Yau and a variety of Kodaira dimension $\kappa$ is a variety of Kodaira dimension $\kappa$.  Thus, counterexamples that are Calabi-Yau varieties give rise to counterexamples of positive Kodaira dimension.

Comment: I agree with Jason, and in fact there are similar examples even for threefolds of Kodaira dimension 1.  I bet they exist for Kodaira dimension 2 as well; I just don't know any offhand.  My guess would be that the Kodaira dimension doesn't really make a difference here until you hit general type and finiteness of models kicks in.